# Increment column value in mysql based on same ID

Tags: mysql

This is my table's current status.

```
id  operation  position
------------------------
1   EDIT          0
1   DELETE        0
2   VIEW          0
3   DELETE        0
3   VIEW          0
3   EDIT          0
```

I want to update position value in mysql say if for `id = 1` 1st entry set to 0 second occurrence for same id incremented by 1. So my final output should be like

```
id  operation  position
------------------------
1   EDIT          0
1   DELETE        1
2   VIEW          0
3   DELETE        0
3   VIEW          1
3   EDIT          2
```

How can i achive that, any hints ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get RowNumber() with Partition in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589707/how-to-get-rownumber-with-partition-in-mysql)

Comment: Remember, there's no row order in MySQL, so when inputting the data, there needs to be some method of establishing which row is 'first' already in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @prev_id = 0;
set @count = 0;

update actions inner join
(select @count := IF(@prev_id = id, @count + 1, 0) as count, @prev_id := id as prev_id, operation
from actions
order by id) as updated
on actions.id = updated.prev_id and actions.operation = updated.operation
set actions.position = updated.count
```

HTH

Edit: I named the table `actions`. Also, there was no column to uniquely identify a record, so I used combination of `id` and `operation`.

Comment: Er, this doesn't work (unless you delete that 'unique key'). In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, the PK's 'fall-back' position is to return operations in alphabetical order - which is not what the OP wanted

Comment: @Strawberry, Could you please elaborate your point? It really sounds confusing to me specifically at points `unless you delete that 'unique key'` and `In the absence of an ORDER BY clause`.

Comment: If it's working fine then great - and, to be fair, in this particular scenario you probably don't have a lot of other options. For the future, you should probably include a timestamp column.

Comment: @Harsh. Test it yourself. Compare your result set with Vicky's. Here's a fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8750e/1

Comment: I posted after testing it (I didn't use sqlfiddle though). The `select` portion is just another way on how to return row number based on certain column, and then updated the table. I am just confused about `unless you delete that 'unique key'` portion of your comment. Also, I tend to answer based on an assumption that OP never post full table structure. So obviously, they are required to modify given answer to suit their actual objective.

Comment: In MySQL, a table is not strictly a table unless it has a PRIMARY KEY. However, the act of constructing a composite PRIMARY KEY on (id,operation) will prevent your solution from working, as the rows will 'naturally' be returned in the 'wrong' order.

Comment: Okay. But as I pointed out in my answer and in previous comment, since there were no known primary keys in the given question. In order to explain the logic, I posted my answer that way, and OP is free to modify as per actual objective, which again I might add, be known to us or not. So the answer is correct in the context of question posted here. The statement `In MySQL, a table is not strictly a table unless it has a PRIMARY KEY` is not limited to `MySQL`. This is a mandatory constraint for any `RDBMS`.