# RowNumber based on reference number in MySql Select

Tags: mysql

I Have a MySQl Table which is having a refnum column and some datas .
combination of three columns is the unique index of my table.
Now i want to fetch all the rows from the table, but based on the reference number i want to add the row number.
[image]

output like 
[image]

How is it possible ????

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: My issue was resolved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589707/how-to-get-rownumber-with-partition-in-mysql Thank You

Comment: So the result is in alphabetical order?