# SQL, get the highest payment month of each year

Tags: mysql

I currently have this that shows me the total of how much the amount is per month. What i want to get from this, is to show the month that made the highest amount per each year.

```
SELECT year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate) , SUM(amount) 
FROM classicmodels.payments
GROUP BY year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate)
ORDER BY paymentDate ASC;
```

Here is the table that i want to only show the month that got the highest amount for each year

[image: img result]

Answer (score 0):

Give `SUM(Amount)` a column alias, `ORDER BY <that alias> DESC` and add `TOP(1)` to the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
SELECT y, m, amount
FROM (
   SELECT YEAR(paymentDate) AS y, MONTH(paymentDate) AS m, 
          amount,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(paymentDate) ORDER BY amount DESC) AS rn
FROM classicmodels.payments) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Note:** In case of ties the query return an arbitrary month. To return all months having the biggest amount use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Because this is in sql-server and the OVER clause will not work on mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` you can assign sequence number for each records based on your criteria, and select the record with sequence 1.
Sample below;

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT year(paymentDate) year_val, month(paymentDate) month_val, SUM(amount) amt_val,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year(paymentDate) ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) AS ROW_ORDER
    FROM classicmodels.payments
    GROUP BY year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate)
)   AS  D
WHERE   D.ROW_ORDER = 1
```

There are lot of other ways to achieve the same.

and `WHERE   D.ROW_ORDER = n` --you will return the n'th highest for each year.

Comment: Because this is in sql-server and the OVER clause will not work on mysql workbench.

Comment: when i post this answer, the sql-server tag was there. Sorry i don't have experience in MySql. But you can try some think similar to ROW_NUMBER, eg:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589707/how-to-get-rownumber-with-partition-in-mysql